# How can I sort contours from left to right and top to bottom in a consistent manner

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a problem that extracts rectangular boxes from image and sort those rectangular boxes sequentially. Code that I tried is:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Load image, grayscale, adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread('3.jpg')
result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,51,9)

# Fill rectangular contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

# Morph open
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=4)
plt.imshow(thresh)

# Draw rectangles
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: [cv2.boundingRect(x)[1], cv2.boundingRect(x)[0]])
# cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0] + cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[1] * image.shape[1], reverse=True)
i = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
#     print("Area:", area)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    
#     cv2.rectangle(image, (x+8, y+8), (x + w-8, y + h-8), (36,255,12), 1)
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('{}.jpg'.format(i), roi)
    i += 1


cv2.imwrite('output_image.jpg', image)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Image used to detect and extract contours: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OmrT.jpg).
I want to extract the boxes containing numbers in order 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-----32. The above code extracts boxes in random order, sometimes from left-to-right and sometimes from right-to-left.

[Edited]
Images that yield contour in order 4-3-2-1 8-7-6-5...
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR9Gz.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVGuV.jpg)

Images that yield contour in order 1-2-3-4  5-6-7-8...
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8nAV.jpg)
[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3asL.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of x-y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111798/how-to-sort-a-list-of-x-y-coordinates)

Comment: It worked partially. I tested on 6 images and 4 images returned contours sequentially but contours of 2 images are obtained in the order 4-3-2-1..8-7-6-5..12-11-10-9........

Comment: Please add two of the successful and both erroneous images to your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65897395/edit) it.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/21/ordering-coordinates-clockwise-with-python-and-opencv/

Comment: Hi! Does this solve your problem? [Python: Sorting items from top left to bottom right with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66946804/13552470)

Comment: It worked partially on my case.

Answer (score 3):

It's the orientation – or: the rotation – of the paper, that decides, whether simply checking the `(x, y)` coordinates of the contours' bounding boxes is sufficient or not.

So, I'd simply stick to some good old comparison method, e.g. [this earlier answer from me on the same issue implemented in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54940056/11089932). Unfortunately, using [the old way using the `cmp` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter) in `sorted` was removed entirely in Python 3. Nevertheless, we can use `cmp_to_key` from the `functools` module to get that functionality mapped to a proper `key` function.

Now, first, let's create the comparison method:

```py
def contour_sort(a, b):

    br_a = cv2.boundingRect(a)
    br_b = cv2.boundingRect(b)

    if abs(br_a[1] - br_b[1]) <= 15:
        return br_a[0] - br_b[0]

    return br_a[1] - br_b[1]
```

The `abs(...) <= 15` (or any other proper threshold) is needed for the cases, where the right boxes are higher than the left boxes (i.e. the main problem).

Then, add this line to your imports:

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key
```

Finally, replace the `key` function in your `sorted` call to that:

```py
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cmp_to_key(contour_sort))
```

Doing so, I can extract the correct order for all the given images.

If someone can provide a simple `key` function without the need of a comparison method, I'd be very interested in that! I couldn't find one myself.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```