# How to assign specific IDs to specific contours in OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying to identify squares on a chess Board and assign them them a ID which will be their square numbers like a1, a2, h1, ...h8. I applied contour detection on the image of the chess Board with some pre-editing like first converting the to grayscale, then canny edge detection along with houghlines. This is the result that I got.
[Image with contours detected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD0MN.png)

I successfully got the required 64 contours but I am not able to assign them their respective IDs like this :
[Chess Squares Notations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58gV4.png) I tried iterating through the contours but they were differently arranged every time.

How do I assign IDs(which are basically chess square notations) to the 64 contours ?

Comment: Calculate the center of each contour, and sort using the centers' `(x, y)` coordinates.

Comment: You could also build a dictionary mapping your IDs with the square centroids.

Comment: @HansHirse In this way , I am either able to sort them either vertically or horizontally but not in a grid like system. If I do it wrt x coordinate of the center of contour, then the columns (example - b1, b2, b3, b4...) are randomly arrange and a similar problem occurs if  I do it wrt y coordinate. How do I sort using both x and y.

Comment: You can have sort functions w.r.t. two variables!? [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65901643/11089932), I've actually implemented that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is for ever contours calculate its centroid and give that point some id , now when you iterate through new set of contours calculate their centroids.
Now you have 2 set for centroids , `previous_c` and `current_c`, You have already assigned every `previous_c` a given id and now for that `previous_c` find the closest `current_c` (you can use Euclidian distance or Manhattan distance) and assign it the same ID. So basically you are doing object tracking but for contours .